# Make a variable in app_controller access in app_model

Tags: cakephp

In my cakephp application I have some logic in beforeFilter method in app_controller.php which picks up a value.

```
function beforeFilter(){
    $this->oCurrentOrganisation = $organisation["Organisation"];
}
```

In this manner the property oCurrentOrganisation is accessible in all controllers.

I require to use this value from within the beforeSave in the app_model.php ... what is the best way to pass the variable's value.

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Comment: you might want to explain your problem in more detail

Answer (score 0):

does this logic have to be in beforeRender()?
this is quite late to save to the model.
one would need more details on what you are trying to achieve.

but either way you can always pass on stuff to the model like so

$this->Model->customVar = 'foo';

or via method (and assign the content to a variable)

$this->Model->customMethod('foo');

if you do that before save() you can count on it in beforeSave().

Comment: I was mistaken logic happens in the beforeFilter ... and I am afraid the solution is not good enough since I want the value in all models and i don't want to go through thousands of lines of code and assign the value to all model instances. :S

Comment: what exactly do you have to pass to the model? you can always store stuff globally using Configure::write() and later Configure::read()